# Using RoboSpice with Roboguice

Tags: android, roboguice, robospice

Is there any example that shows how we can inject a class of SpringAndroidSpiceRequest object into our activity. This is my class

```
public class GenericService<E> extends  SpringAndroidSpiceRequest<E> {

    public GenericService(Class<E> clazz) {
        super(clazz);

    }

    @Override
    public E loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Now i cannot provide a no-argument constructor for this class, because i cannot simply say E.class in the constructor due limimations of the design. What i can do is say

```
class MyService extends GenericService<Login.Response>{

    public MyService() {
        super(Login.Response.class);

    }

}
```

and then inject a value of the MyService into my activity. But this approch would mean having to create a specialized class for each of my request objects [ there are about 32 :( ]. Can anyone tell me how can i achieve what i am trying to do ?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 2):

In our real apps, we do have a specialized request class for each request. That's the model of robospice. Inheritance can help to generalize requests sometimes, but you usually endup creating a request per rest service.